# how to handle opencv error with a non-exception code base

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling, service

I have a non-exception grpc service code base which uses “error code return” strategy to deals with all kinds of errors(when an error happens(not all, only the unhandleable ones), it causes a chain reaction all the way to the service response call and response the client request call with an error code)
now I have to rely on some third party library (say openCV), and I'm wondering how to handle the potential errors that may caused by openCV apis.

code examples:

```
#include<opencv2/opencv/hpp>
int A(args)
{
    ...
    int errCode = B();  //this is how i handle all my internal api call or other thrid party same error-style api calls, it returns an int error code and checked
    if(errCode)
    {
        //log...;
        //resouce release...
        return errCode;
    }
    ...
    return 0; //0 means succ call
}
int B(args)
{
    ...
    cv::OPENCV_API(cv::Mat, cv::Mat,...args). // how to handle this api call? 
    ...
}
```

**and here is my questions:**

1.what will happen if something is wrong with the opencv api call, I searched opencv error handling, see that most of it throws exceptions, so the whole service will be aborted?

2. if I don't want to use *try {...} catch {...}* in my code, how should I work with exception-throw style third party code to avlid them from crash my service?

3.say the worst, I have to use *try {...} catch {...}*, how should it be woked out? is some thing like below will work?(means that my service won't abort or cratch):

```
//int A() remains same

int B(args)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        ...
        cv::OPENCV_API(cv::Mat, cv::Mat,...args). // how to handle this api call? 
        ...
    }
    catch
    {
         log...;
         int errCode = -1000;
         return errCode; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**TL;DR** if I don't use throw-exception syntax in my own code, how do I utilize and error-handling with thrid-party code that applys throw-exception syntax?

Comment: Usually, you should try to catch exceptions in your interface when dealing with 3rd party lib you don't know well about it. But as for opencv, if you really want a exception free API, you may try its OUTDATED [C api](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d31/group__objdetect__c.html).

Comment: you may not. that C API is not just outdated, it's been removed since v4.0. the v3.x branch will soon stop receiving maintenance. -- just catch the exception, inspect it, and convert to your error codes. OpenCV internally uses error codes too. @Harold that link goes to docs for _one specific module's_ old C bindings. even in v3.x already a lot of the old C API was axed.

Comment: appreciated  both of your replys. I'm using opencv4.x, so C api is not aviliable. and I'm going with my third option, which is also what Christoph suggests, just catch it and translate it into my own error code.